# Fermats little theorem contradiction by looking at remainder.

Tags: group-theory

If we have a number $g$ with the order $p-1$ and $p$ is a prime.

And we assume that $g$ can generate a number a with the order $m$ that does not divide $p-1$.

We could then use the division theorem:

$p-1 = mq + r$ where $0 ≤ r < m$

In that case $r$ can't be zero, because if $m$ doesn't divide $p-1$ a remainder $r$ can't be zero, right?

But how would this contradict fermats little theorem? I struggle to understand this...

Comment: That the order $m$ divides $p-1$ is another statement, we only need fermat's little theorem to ensure $g^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ and we can prove that the order must divide an exponent (here $p-1$) giving the value $1$.Hence a consequence of Fermat's little theorem is that $m\mid p-1$ must hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that $a$ is "of order $m$" here presumably means *multiplicative* order, meaning that $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^m=1$ mod $p$. By the Division Algorithm for integers, we have $p-1=mq+r$ for some quotient $q$ and some $0\le r<m$, in any case. Invoke Fermat's little theorem to obtain, mod p,
$$
1 \;=\; a^{p-1} \;=\; a^{mq+r} \;=\; (a^m)^q\cdot a^r \;=\; 1\cdot a^r\;=\; a^r
$$
Because $m$ does not divide $p-1$, $r$ cannot be $0$. Then $0< r<m$, contradicting the assumption that $m$ was the smallest positive integer such that $a^m=1\mod p$.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the fast answer!

But why are you saying that m was the smaller positive integer such that $a^m=1 mod p$?
Shouldn't that be p-1, as I said? Since that's the order, and m is just a "part of" the number p-1, hence why I used the division theorem.

Could you just give me something to point me in the right direction of thought. 

Does the $a^r = 1$ hold just because I said m would not divide p-1? So the remainder can't be zero.
Otherwise the theorem would hold and r = 0?

I'm sorry, I'm really trying to understand this.

Comment: @JonasElmesten, I'll revise a little to try to be clearer.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it much better now! Thank you for your time, Paul!